# Getting error "Error parsing insert statement for table ROOT.LOAD_SQL" while using ltrim in sql loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I trying to load the datas from data file to the database table load_sql using sql loader. I have data like below in the data file.

```
empid,ename
1,Raja,**Kanchi
2,Poo,**Kanchi
3,Bhasker,**Kanchi
4,Siva,**Kanchi
```

I have to load to load it in the load_sql table like below format:

```
1,Raja,Kanchi
2,Poo,Kanchi
3,Bhasker,Kanchi
4,Siva,Kanchi
```

I have written a control file with help of char manipulation function for inserting records in third column but im getting error:

```
options(skip = 1,Errors = 100, direct = True)
load data
infile 'D:\SQLLDR\control.ctl'
truncate into table load_sql
when city = 'Kanchi'
fields terminated by ',' 
optionally enclosed by '"'
(
empid,
ename,
X filler,
city "ltrim(:city,*)"
)
```

I'm getting the error like

```
'SQL*Loader-951: Error calling once/load initialization
ORA-02373: Error parsing insert statement for table ROOT.LOAD_SQL.
ORA-00936: missing expression'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your control file.  Try this:

```
options(skip = 1,Errors = 100, direct = True)
load data
infile 'D:\SQLLDR\control.ctl'  <-- This doesn't look like a data file name?
truncate into table load_sql
when (city = '**Kanchi')
fields terminated by ',' 
optionally enclosed by '"'
(
empid,
ename,
city "ltrim(:city, '*')"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ltrim(:city,*)
            ^
            |
        this is invalid
```

Should have been

```
ltrim(:city, '*')
```

or, possibly,

```
replace(:city, '*', '')
```

Comment: thanks littlefoot....Now i have change my code as ltrim(:city,'*') and i didnt receive any error but the records arent loaded into the table

Comment: Looks like your `when` condition is not being met. Check the log file and the discard file.

Comment: You're welcome. As of your new problems, I agree with @William.

Comment: As the other commentators said, you're filtering by:  when city = 'Kanchi' ,but you're getting '**Kanchi' on the file.